# $z_x-2xz_y=0\:for\:z=z\left(x,y\right),\:x^2+y^2-1=0,\:z=4$ - What should I do next?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$z_x-2xz_y=0\:for\:z=z\left(x,y\right),\:x^2+y^2-1=0,\:z=4$

$\frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{dy}{2y}=\frac{dz}{0}$

I get

$z=C_1$ and $x\sqrt{y}=C_2$

Following $f\left(C_1\right)=C_2$ we get:

$f\left(z\right)=x\sqrt{y}$

But what's the next step?

I thought about

$x^2+y^2-1=0\:\:\: => 4x^2+4y^2-4=0\:\:\: => 4x^2+4y^2-z=0\:\:\: => 4x^2=z-4y^2 => x^2=\frac{z}{4}-y^2 => x=\sqrt{\frac{z}{4}-y^2}$

Then

$f\left(z\right)=\sqrt{\frac{z}{4}-y^2}\cdot \sqrt{y}$

Then

$x\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{\frac{z}{4}-y^2}\cdot \sqrt{y} => x=\sqrt{\frac{z}{4}-y^2} => x^2=\frac{z}{4}-y^2 => 4x^2+4y^2=z$

What do you think about that?

Comment: Why not $z = f(x\sqrt y)$ ?

Comment: I wanted to write to you about this in my other thread. Because z=4 and we could do nothing about it

Comment: I am afraid you committed a mistake in the $C_2=x\sqrt{y}$ calculation. $\frac {dx}{1}=-\frac{dy}{2x}$

Comment: You are right. $\frac{dx}{1}=-\frac{1}{2}\:\frac{dy}{x} => x\:dx=-\frac{1}{2}\:dy => \frac{x^2}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}y\:+\:C_2 => \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}y\:=\:C_2$ But still $z=f\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}y\:\right)$ doesnt make sense to calculate, there's no way to do anything further with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z_x-2xz_y=0$$
You correctly wrote the Charpit-Lagrange equations.

After correcting the mistake in solving, the general solution of the PDE is :
$$z(x,y)=F(y+x^2)$$

with arbitrary function $F$.

CONDITION :

$z=4$ on the cirle $x^2+y^2=1 \quad\implies 4=F(y+(1-y^2)\big)=F(y-y^2+1)$

This is possible any $y$ only if the function $F$ is the constant function $=4$. Thus the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition is
$$z(x,y)=4$$